# Python mysql Connector Error when tying to write to database only when not In Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write some data to a database but only when its not already in the table.  Im using the Variables `data` , `data1` ,`timestamp`, and `name`.My Python MySql Connector looks like this

```
mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Messung (Date,capacity,Cpu,HostID) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Messung WHERE Date = 'timestamp' AND HostID = 'name')""", (timestamp ,data ,data1 ,name))
```

I get the Following Error

```
       mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Messung (Date,capacity,Cpu,HostID) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Messung WHERE Date = 'timestamp' AND HostID = 'name')""", (timestamp ,data ,data1 ,name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 559, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 494, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 396, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Messung WHERE Date = 'timestamp' AND HostID = 'n' at line 1
```

I dont get whats wrong with the Syntax
I also dont want to update an Existing entry just to skip them
SAMPLE DATA:

timestamp=`2019-11-20 00:00:00`

name =`testpc`

data= `18.14`

data1= `58.53`

I am Splitting strings like this

```
2019-11-18 00:00:00 testpc data 11.58 data1 29.20
```

Comment: This looks like it's more of a `SQL` question. Can you share some information about the data set you are working with, including sample data?

Comment: MySQL Insert Syntax doesn't support where clause in it.

Comment: Why are you going to the trouble of splitting strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Insert Syntax doesn't support where clause in it. May be you can try

```
INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.



mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Messung (Date,capacity,Cpu,HostID) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Date = 'timestamp' """, (timestamp ,data ,data1 ,name))
```

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/

Comment: I dont want to update the result . I just want it to be ignored

Comment: Then declare your ignored columns to be unique and use "INSERT IGNORE INTO table" in your query.